# positive phrase has negative score in vader function polarity_scores

Tags: python, vader

In python's `nltk.sentiment.vader`, there is a function called `polarity_scores`, you can try to use the string `no problem` to see the result, which is -0.6.

How could I improve vader's performance. If not, is there any other package that does a better job?

Comment: Please show some code and data. Right now it is not clear what you are doing and what the actual problem is.

Comment: Pls post the code wit the sentence which you are passing in to detect the scores, you can also use from **nltk.sentiment import SentimentAnalyzer** as alternative

Answer (score 0):

HI YOU WONT BELIEVE THIS BUT I WAS HAVING THE SAME PROBLEM AND NO ONE HELPED ME EITHER!!!!!!!!!!!

It's a year late and you probably don't care, but how I went about this is to go into the vader.py file - (you can find this file by running nltk.sentiment.vader.**file** in your Python shell) - and inside the file there is a dictionary of Negate Words within the class VaderConstants, add "no" to the list.

Now there is one more step. You need to run

```
sid.lexicon.pop('no')
```

where

```
sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
```

Because if a word is in the lexicon then it would not be treated as a negate word!